# PreferenceFragment layout values

Tags: java, android, layout, styles

I'm creating an app with a main menu, one of these menu items will open up a PreferenceFragment. To create unity within the app I'd like the main menu to look as close to the PreferenceFragment as possible. Basically all the xml values I can use to create menu items that look similar to those in the PreferenceFragment.

**Examples of values I need**: text size and color (for both title and summary text) and padding values.

I could guess at it but that could take awhile and may not be accurate. There has to be a better way to do it.

Here is what I have so far:
**Main Menu** (the menu I want to look like the PreferenceFragment): https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcqYJ.png
**Preferences** (the PreferenceFragment): https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWMin.png

Here are the layout values I have so far the menu item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/menu_item"
              android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1"
              android:paddingLeft="10dp">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/menu_item_title"
              android:textSize="20sp"
              android:textColor="@android:color/white"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/menu_item_description"
              android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am using a ListFragment with a custom ListAdapter to return the above layout with the required String values and display it in the list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should use themes and styles if you are looking for the text size and color to be the same throughout the app.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I don't want to change how the PreferenceFragment looks though, I want to mimic it's design, not change everything to my own theme.

Comment: When you create the style/theme, you create that consistency. It's like css for Android. You can apply it to Fragments, or other activities.

Comment: I want to mimic the look of the PreferenceFragment because it looks good. Maybe the PreferenceFragment uses an internal theme which we could apply to the main menu?

Comment: I just found this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml (look at line 947 and beyond) this could be the answer...

Comment: That would be one approach :)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer anyway! I'll let you know how it goes and if I figure it out I'll post a follow-up answer